# Is there any way to find user-data execution logs for mac-ec2 similar to what we have for linux-ec2 (/var/log/cloud-init.log)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, macos, amazon-ec2

Is there any way to find user-data execution logs for mac-ec2 similar to what we have for linux-ec2.

- For linux instance the user-data stdout can be seen here: **/var/log/cloud-init.log**
- when I check for mac-ec2 I found the stdout location is: **/var/log/amazon/ec2/ec2-macos-init.log**

but, **ec2-macos-init.log** only showing the user-data execution status.
What I need is the step by step execution logs so that I can check which command is failing from my user-data script.

Can someone help me here?
Thanks

Comment: It _might_ be in `/usr/local/aws/ec2-macos-init/instances/<instance-id>/`. See: [EC2 macOS Init is the launch daemon used to initialize Mac instances within EC2](https://github.com/aws/ec2-macos-init)

Comment: No its not there, I've checked it!

Answer (score 1):

I found it at /var/log/amazon/ec2/ec2-macos-init.log

It shows both the STDOUT and STDERR in separate chunks, but all of the information I needed to debug the issue is there.

```
2021/10/16 17:25:48.706183 Successfully completed module [ExecuteUserData] (type: userdata, group: 4) with message: successfully ran user data with stdout: [...] and stderr: [...]
```

The ellipsis actually show output from my script.

Comment: So the question have wrong information ? It says it show only few stdout

Comment: I updated my answer with an example line I see in the log. The ellipsis actually shows the output from my script in both placeholders for stdout and stderr